# MongoDB as MySQL cache

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, caching, redis

I just had this idea and thinks it's a good solution for this problem but I ask if there are some downsides to this method. I have a webpage that often queries database, as much as 3-5 queries per page load. Each query is making a dozen(literally) joins and then each of these queries results are used for another queries to construct PHP objects. Needless to say the load times are ridiculous even on the cloud but it's the way it works now.

I thought about storing the already constructed objects as JSON, or in MongoDB - BSON format. Will it be a good solution to use MongoDB as a cache engine of this type? Here is the example of how I think it will work:

1. When the user opens the page, if there is no data in Mongo with the proper ID, the queries to MySQL fire, each returning data that is being converted to a properly constructed object. The object is sent to the views and is converted to JSON and saved in Mongo.
2. If there was data in Mongo with the corresponding ID, it is being sent to PHP and converted.
3. When some of the data changes in MySQL (administrator edits/deletes content) a delete function is fired that will delete the edited/deleted object in MongoDB as well.

Is it a good way to use MongoDB? What are the downsides of this method? Is it better to use Redis for this task? I also need NoSQL for other elements of the project, that's why I'm considering to use one of these two instead of memcache.

[MongoDB as a cache for frequent joins and queries from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010438/mongodb-as-a-cache-for-frequent-joins-and-queries-from-mysql?rq=1) has some information, but it's totally irrelevant.

Comment: Did you consider to optimize your mysql database schema so that you no longer need dozens of joins to build a page? What's wrong with using the technology you have and build the cache in mysql? The more technology you add, the more points of failure you have and the more knowhow is required to maintain your application.

Comment: @Philipp yes, you're right about the more technologies used the harder the management gets, but it's not a simple database-frontend project, it's a system made a couple of years ago that needs optimization for the web side of it. The schema was de-normalized as much as it's possible for less joins to be present, but it's just too complicated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you would be better off using memcached or Redis to cache the query results. MongoDB is more of a full database than a cache. While both memcached and Redis are optimized for caching.

However, you could implement your cache as a two-level cache. Memcached, for example, does not guarantee that data will stay in the cache. (it might expire data when the storage is full). This makes it hard to implement a system for tags (so, for example, you add a tag for a MySQL table, and then you can trigger expiration for all query results associated with that table). A common solution for this, is to use memcached for caching, and a second slower, but more reliable cache, which should be faster than MySQL though. MongoDB could be a good candidate for that (as long as you can keep the queries to MongoDB simple).

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot to mention, the expectations are that there will be 50-100k objects in the database, about 5-100kB each. So it's not an option to use only RAM as cache for it's small capacity.

Comment: Then I definitely think it would be good to use a two-level cache. Some implementations offer the possibility of using a priority for the object to cache. This is especially for expiration when the storage is full, and which objects to store in the faster, and which to store in the slower cache.

Comment: Understood, glad you've suggested two-level caching, it might solve every problem I have. What about the system to use as a slower cache? MongoDB or Redis? As I see it's Mongo all the way due to it's flexibility.

Comment: Afaik, you can use both (though I'm not an expert on Redis). I think Redis would be faster, so in that case, I would use Redis.

Comment: Redis keeps a copy of everything in memory. I would add the primary cache layer and measure performance again.  You may find the secondary cache unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can go with Memcached or Redis for caching objects. Mongodb can be also used as a cache. I use mongodb for caching aggregation results, since it has advantage of wide range of queries as well unlike Memcached.

For example, in a tagging application, if I have to display page count corresponding to each tag, it scans whole table for a `group by` query. So I have a `cronjob` which computes that group by query and cache the aggregation result in Mongo. This works perfectly well for me in production. You can do this for countless other complex computations as well.

Also mongodb [capped collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) and [TTL collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) are perfect for caching.

Comment: Please explain why would you use cronjob instead of simply running updates when certain time passes from the last update? It will be lighter in situations when only some part of the data is queried and the other part is idle. For example, for a web store, I don't need to cache the PC products as much as perfumery and other similar stuff right before valentine's day.

Comment: Yup, sure if you don't need cronjobs avoid them. They are costly. I just gave an example, the way I use in production. Even stackexchange has cronjobs for aggregations and ranking of users ;)

Comment: Yeah, for some parts of the page they are the way to go, like front page elements.

Comment: For expiration of records, in mongo you have TTL indexes. Check out the links in answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using them too, thank you for the links!